# Does the "object" here refer to the object class

Tags: python, python-3.x, language-lawyer

I saw in the Python documentation for defining an emulating container type https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types, it states:

> **object.**__len__(self)
>     Called to implement the built-in function len()...
>     ...
>
> **object.**__getitem__(self, key)
>     Called to implement evaluation of self[key]. For sequence types ...
>     ...
> ......

I wonder it seems instructing to add the `__len__` function as the attribute of `object` class, but if you make a emulating class e.g. EmuList

```
class EmuList:
    def __len__(self):
        pass
    ...
```

The `__len__` function should be attached to `EmuList` but `object`, although EmuList inherited from object class. What does `object` prefix in `object.__len__` really mean in this context ?

Answer (score 2):

It is not spelled out explicitly by the documentation, but as far as I can tell it is to represent the fact that these are methods that can be implemented by arbitrary classes. It does not represent the `object` type, because many of the special methods are not implemented for `object`, like `__len__` and `__getitem__`.

Comment: Thank you @jasmijn, I also think it the way like what you put here.

Answer (score 0):

It mostly refers to any object in Python(Class object, Instance object etc. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-definition-syntax), example quoted below(from https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__), here as with class.bases, "class" means class type object and instance.class means instance type object(Intance object)

> Special Attributes The implementation adds a few special read-only
> attributes to several object types, where they are relevant. Some of
> these are not reported by the dir() built-in function.
>
> object.**dict** A dictionary or other mapping object used to store an
> object’s (writable) attributes.
>
> instance.**class** The class to which a class instance belongs.
>
> class.**bases** The tuple of base classes of a class object.
>
> definition.**name** The name of the class, function, method,
> descriptor, or generator instance.
>
> definition.**qualname** The qualified name of the class, function,
> method, descriptor, or generator instance.
>
> New in version 3.3.
>
> definition.**type_params** The type parameters of generic classes,
> functions, and type aliases.
>
> New in version 3.12.
>
> class.**mro** This attribute is a tuple of classes that are considered
> when looking for base classes during method resolution.
>
> class.mro() This method can be overridden by a metaclass to customize
> the method resolution order for its instances. It is called at class
> instantiation, and its result is stored in **mro**.
>
> class.**subclasses**() Each class keeps a list of weak references to
> its immediate subclasses. This method returns a list of all those
> references still alive. The list is in definition order. Example: